# UDDI error while creating a web service in java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I have created one web service in java using eclipse and that web service is going to connect a sql database which is on our server.When i am trying this web service with UDDI registry i am getting this as output on the body portion

"IWAB0135E An unexpected error has occurred.
UDDIException
The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is "http://localhost:8080/ResourceA/services/Myservice?wsdl" and the WSA Action = . If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator."

**NOTE :-**  ***can any one please send me the proper steps to use web service in UDDI*.**
is my way of coding wright? if not please let me know the proper way.

Please find my sources for reference

```
package pkg;

import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Myservice 
{

public List getCustomerId(@WebParam(name = "ID") String ID){
    String user = "sa";
    String password = "peritus!@#";
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:122.165.86.7:SampleWebService";
    String OracleDriver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List value = new ArrayList();
    try{

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select EmployeeCode from SampleTable where ID = '" + ID + " '");
        pstmt.setString(1, ID);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
 {
            value.add(rs.getString("EmployeeCode"));
        }
    }

    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return value;
    }    }
```

thanks for your precious time!...